# Placement of window AC in open living space

Tags: hvac

I am struggling to find good advice on the placement of window AC units in an (half) open living space. The units are supposed to cover the green area, which is relatively open (total size 790 square foot). We are pretty much set on LGs dual inverter units with 9,500 BTU (450 sq ft, LG LW1019IVSM) or 14,000 BTU (800 sq ft, LG LW1517IVSM). My current thinking is to use two 9,500 BTU units. One in window 1 and one in window 3 or 5. Does that make sense? What are guidelines to cover a space like this?

[image]

Comment: With window units, all you can really do is choose a window and see how the units you have work out - then either move what windows they are in, or add circulation fans to help distribute.

Comment: Make sure your neighborhood doesn't have restrictions on window mounted A/C units.  If there's no HOA, there's probably not a rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use window 12 over number 1 because that is where the heat load is and the room is larger. 
3 or 5 are both good options but I would use 3 because of  the proximity for the discharge to blow towards the family room.
If this were my place I would install mini splits , last week I saw an advertisement for a top brand 12k btu mini split with a 10 year warranty for 475.00 installed, I am sure that means you have to put the power in but hanging a split and mounting the outside unit on a plastic pad can be done very quickly, there are even some full DIY options out there but they are more expensive. 
The split units can be mounted above windows or on walls and can add value to your home including providing a efficient heat source in the winter

Answer (score 1):

Choose your window based on your usage and what is important to you. Two things to consider, the cooling effect of course, and the noise and aesthetics. If the cooling is more important to you than the noise, then mount in the room where you spend the most time or would get the most comfort from it.

Two units will give you much better coverage than one unit. However, you can overcome this with fans. Use small air circulating fans to distribute the cooling affect around the rooms. Remember that hot air rises so if the fan is in the room to be cooled, then point it high and out the door to move the warm air out.

[image]